# Recommendation for an analytics framework for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, analytics

I just want something basic that can tell me how often the app is used and what features are used the most.

Oh yeah, and I'd really like something free :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PreEmptive Solutions is offering an [analytics framework](http://www.preemptive.com/windowsphone7.html) that is free until the end of this month.

Comment: I believe the PreEmptive stuff would be free for the rest of the year.

Comment: @samidip: I remember reading that too, but when I looked at their website yesterday it said something about all licenses expiring on the 31st of March.

Comment: They've got a limited version of the framework that they're offering for free with no end date

Answer (score 4):

We use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html).  It's free, easy to use and relatively powerful.  Certainly powerful enough to meet your current requirements.

Answer (score 3):

mtiks has a free solution, however it is currently in beta

http://www.mtiks.com/wp7analytics

otherwise theres dotfuscator, but that has a monthly fee

edit:

I should add I am not sure if mtiks can give stats on specific features, but for free it's a good solution.

Also it looks like they may have brought it out of beta since I last checked it out.

Comment: This is also a pretty good solution for quick, simple analytics.

Comment: You can fire your own events with a name and description, so you can also log specific features if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Extensible Web Analytics Framework for Microsoft Silverlight, WPF, and Windows Phone 7 Applications.
http://msaf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note that this is currently not quite working with 7.1 / Mango at the moment, but should soon be fixed, maybe

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Equatec (the folks who make the profiler product) also has an analytics framework. (They are running a special where if you use their product for a bit you can earn the commercial versions of the profiler).

Answer (score 0):

There is one more analytics service provider [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).
[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/technical-info.html) supports iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, JavaME and HTML5